# Find Column Name in Excel sheet if string matches

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two sheets sheet1 and sheet2.There is a text in sheet1 'customer'.I want to find the column name like A from sheet2 if text 'customer' found in a cell of row 1 of sheet2.I am using Match function but it is returning only the index.Is there a way to find the column name like A?
[image]

Comment: Hi there, it sounds like you would be looking for a `HLOOKUP` formula here. It's not very clear from your description, perhaps you could provide some example data and more explanation of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for reply i have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took me a while of playing around but this will work for EXACT matches.

As the example data states `Client` and not `Clients` it returns an error and therefore is forced to state `"Not Found"`. In cell B2 of sheet 1, copied down is the formula:

```
=IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH(A2,Sheet2!$A$1:$D$1,0),4),"1",""),"Not Found")
```

[image: Example]